# Changing the grid layout from 4 columns to 2 columns messes up the cells order

Tags: html, css

I am trying to transform a `grid` layout from a 4 columns into a 2 columns by using a media query. The issue is that if and when I do that the grid messes up with the items order.

Actually it works as it was designed to: it takes the HTML elements and places them from left to right into their own cell accordingly, but this "sorting" isn't good for me.

I've written the HTML elements for a 4 column grid and it only works this way.

```
        <article class="page_1">
            <div class="short_info">
                <div class="info info1"></div>
                <div class="info info2"></div>
                <div class="info info3"></div>
                <div class="info info4"></div>
                <span>EASY TO USE</span>
                <span>DETAILED STATISTICS</span>
                <span>EASY TO CUSTOMIZE</span>
                <span>SECURITY</span>
                <p>You don't have to be a computer nerd to use LPR.</p>
                <p>You will always have all the necessary data at your disposal. Properly used, LPR never fails.
                </p>
                <p>You want a special feature? Tell us about it and we'll implement it.</p>
                <p> No one can delete or change data in your program. Every action a user takes in LPR is   recorded in a log file.
                </p>
            </div>
        </article>
```

```
.short_info {
    display: grid;
    width: 95vw;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    min-height: 300px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.short_info .info {
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
}

.short_info .info1 {
    background-image: url(../img/laptop.svg);
}

.short_info .info2 {
    background-image: url(../img/bar-chart.svg);
}

.short_info .info3 {
    background-image: url(../img/pen.svg);
}

.short_info .info4 {
    background-image: url(../img/shield.svg);
}

.short_info span {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.short_info p {
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

I've designed it like this because this way I could align all the rows perfectly. The `icons` are aligned to each other, the `spans` are aligned to each other and the `paragraphs` are aligned to each other. There isn't one `span` or `p` that is placed lower or upper than its neighbor. They go like this:

```
icon     icon     icon     icon
span     span     span     span
p        p        p        p
```

Unfortunately, this design does not allow me to simply use media queries and change to `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);`, because this will display the information in a messed up order. It will go like this:

```
icon     icon
icon     icon
span     span
span     span
p        p
p        p
```

which is not pretty at all.

I've thought of another way of designing this, but I can't get the items to perfectly align.
I've put one `icon`, one `span`, and one `p` inside a `div` and made a grid with just only one row.
I've used flex to try and align the elements inside the `div` but I can't align them on the same line as I previously did.

```
<div class="short_info">
    <div>
        <div class="info info1"></div>
        <span>EASY TO USE</span>
        <p>You don't have to be a computer nerd to use Metrici LPR.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="info info2"></div>
        <span>DETAILED STATISTICS</span>
        <p>
            You will always have all the necessary data at your disposal. Properly used, Metrici LPR never fails.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="info info3"></div>
        <span>EASY TO CUSTOMIZE</span>
        <p>You want a special feature? Tell us about it and we'll implement it.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="info info4"></div>
        <span>SECURITY</span>
        <p>
            No one can delete or change data in your program. Every action a user takes in Metrici LPR is recorded in a
            log file.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.short_info {

    margin-bottom: 100px;
    display: grid;
    width: 95vw;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.short_info div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.short_info .info {
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
}
```

this allows me to properly resize them from 4 columns to 2 when I resize the window, but it will align the elements inside independently, not on the same rows like the previous grid.

The new alignment looks like this:

```
icon     icon     icon     icon
         span     span
span                   
                           span
         p        p
p
                           p
```

The elements get aligned by flex depending on the height and width of each individual element.

I basically have two questions at this time:

1. How can I go from 4 columns to 2 columns using the first layout ?
2. How can I align all of the flex items on the same lines ?

Comment: After some tinkering I've discovered that if I set `justify-content` in `.short_info div` from `justify-content: space-between;` to `justify-content: start;`. Basically, if I let every element from every grid cell to align at start, they will align beautifully on a horizontal line, just like I've wanted.
As for the first question, I'm thinking that changing from 4 columns to 2 columns in the way the HTML elements are written will require quite a hefty chunk of JS to maybe listen on a resize event and change the HTML tags accordingly back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

it's possible to modify ur template to a 2 column template, if you add some HTML and change the CSS a little.

For the first question, check this code:

```css
.short_info {
    display: grid;
    width: 95vw;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 50%);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    min-height: 300px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
     grid-template-areas: 
    "info1 info2"
    "span1 span2"
    "p1 p2"
    "info3 info4"
    "span3 span4"
    "p3 p4";
}

.short_info .info {
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
        width: 50%;
}

.short_info .info1 {
    background-image: url(../img/laptop.svg);
    grid-area: info1;
}

.short_info .info2 {
    background-image: url(../img/bar-chart.svg);
    grid-area: info2;
}

.short_info .info3 {
    background-image: url(../img/pen.svg);
    grid-area: info3;
}

.short_info .info4 {
    background-image: url(../img/shield.svg);
    grid-area: info4;
}

.short_info span {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.short_info p {
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.span1 {
  grid-area: span1;
}
.span2 {
  grid-area: span2;
}
.span3 {
  grid-area: span3;
}
.span4 {
  grid-area: span4;
}

.p1 {
  grid-area: p1;
}
.p2 {
  grid-area: p2;
}
.p3 {
  grid-area: p3;
}
.p4 {
  grid-area: p4;
}
```

```html
 <article class="page_1">
            <div class="short_info">
                <div class="info info1"></div>
                <div class="info info2"></div>
                <div class="info info3"></div>
                <div class="info info4"></div>
                <span class="span1">EASY TO USE</span>
                <span class="span2">DETAILED STATISTICS</span>
                <span class="span3">EASY TO CUSTOMIZE</span>
                <span class="span4">SECURITY</span>
                <p class="p1">You don't have to be a computer nerd to use LPR.</p>
                <p class="p2">You will always have all the necessary data at your disposal. Properly used, LPR never fails.
                </p>
                <p class="p3">You want a special feature? Tell us about it and we'll implement it.</p>
                <p class="p4"> No one can delete or change data in your program. Every action a user takes in LPR is   recorded in a log file.
                </p>
            </div>
        </article>
```

For the second question (the better option, in my opinion):

you have to set fix height values for the headlines to get all stuff on a line.

Like this:

```css
.short_info {

    margin-bottom: 100px;
    display: grid;
    width: 95vw;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.short_info div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

.short_info .info {
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
}


.short_info span {
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="short_info">
    <div>
        <div class="info info1"></div>
        <span>EASY TO USE</span>
        <p>You don't have to be a computer nerd to use Metrici LPR.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="info info2"></div>
        <span>DETAILED STATISTICS</span>
        <p>
            You will always have all the necessary data at your disposal. Properly used, Metrici LPR never fails.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="info info3"></div>
        <span>EASY TO CUSTOMIZE</span>
        <p>You want a special feature? Tell us about it and we'll implement it.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="info info4"></div>
        <span>SECURITY</span>
        <p>
            No one can delete or change data in your program. Every action a user takes in Metrici LPR is recorded in a
            log file.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So a solution for the first question would be to use `grid-area` to let the grid know where the elements should be placed no matter the number of columns, correct ?
For the second question, do you think that setting a height to the middle element is imperative ? Check my comment at the question. I've only modified `justify-content: start;` and the elements are perfectly aligned

Comment: yea correct. `grid-area` for placing the elements in this structure. If your solution is working without a height in your second question it's fine. I just thought about, that if one headline will always be much longer than the others, it's maybe working better with a height